# What is pushing the same register twice doing?

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to call to a function with no arguments. I know the address of the function is in EAX register.  Why isn't this code doing that:

```
push EAX
push EAX
ret
```

and this one is calling the function:

```
push next_a
push EAX
ret 
next_a:
```

`next_a` is the function I would like to call.  But I know the address of this function is located in EAX

On the first one: what is pushing EAX twice doing?

Comment: Can you post more code? What is "next_a" ? Click "edit" below your question and add more code.

Comment: this is the function i would like to call. but i know the address of this function is located in EAX...

Comment: this is a question from exam i got. i know the easy one is just use call; but the professor said the first example is not working and I'm trying to figure why

Comment: @Jester answered your question : the double push reexecutes the function. You are new so probably you didn't know that you can click the checkmark of an answer to accept it if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow through what happens. Let's call the function `foo`.

```
push eax ; address of foo on the stack
push eax ; address of foo on the stack again
ret      ; picks off the top item from the stack, goes to foo

foo:
; body of function
ret      ; picks off the top item from stack, which is still foo
         ; so invokes itself again
```

Second example:

```
push next_a ; address of next_a on the stack
push eax    ; address of foo on the stack
ret         ; picks off the top item from the stack, goes to foo

foo:
; body of function
ret      ; picks off the top item from stack, which is next_a

next_a:
; execution continues here
```

As such, both versions *do* call `foo` first.
Anyway, if you really just want to call `foo` (XY problem) then use `call eax` and be done with it.

> next_a is the function I would like to call.

Really? If `eax=next_a` then the two pieces of code are exactly equivalent.

Comment: from some reason the professor of the course said the first example isn't calling to this function I'm trying to figure why it's not working well...

Comment: @TalShani: Well, it jumps to the function, but it's not really a `call`, because it doesn't push the same return address that `call` would.

Comment: thanks! do you know what is it  pushing instead the return address?